# HighCharts JS - Getting multiple linear underlays on a scatter plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts, visualization

I'm trying to make some visualisations using the HighCharts javascript library, mainly I'm hoping to make something very similar to what these guys have on their page:

[Research Affiliates - 10Yr Expected Risk & Return](http://www.researchaffiliates.com/AssetAllocation/Pages/Core-Overview.aspx)

Mainly, I'm trying to work out how they managed to get the 2 solid linear areas on the scatter graph that represent the different Sharpe Ratio levels. Is it just a background image, or have they somehow underlayed an area chart under the scatter chart?

[image]

Has anybody got any experience with this, or how to code it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can combine any kind of chart type.

See their [demo of a scatter plot with a regression line](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-regression).

---

As an example of a scatter plot combined with a stacked area chart, see the following code and fiddle:

```
var Y_MAX = 6;
var X_MAX = 5;

$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Scatter plot with stacked area ratio chart'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: X_MAX
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: Y_MAX
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Ratio',
            data: [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: X_MAX, y: 0.4*Y_MAX}]
        }, {
            type: 'area',
            name: 'Ratio',
            data: [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: X_MAX, y: 0.6*Y_MAX}]
        }, {
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Observations',
            data: [1, 0.5, 3.8, 5.5, 3.9, 2.2],
            marker: {
                radius: 8
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kme175ba/1/)

Answer (score 3):

On the web page you are referring to area type series are used to generate triangular shapes in the background.

Area chart demo: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-basic

Area chart API reference: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the heads up on how to combine two charts.
What I actually ended up using was the Polygon Plot type rather than an Area Chart.
I also rendered the labels using `Chart.renderer.label`.
Still tweaking this, but as a whole reference this is my code (minus data taken out)

```js
$(function () {
$('#scatter-plot').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Expected Asset Return Against Volatility'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volatility',
            enabled: true,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '18px',
                fontFamily: 'PT Sans',
            }
        },
        min: 0,
        lineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: '#bfbfbf',
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        tickWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            format: '{value} %',
            style: {
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Real Expected Returns',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '18px',
                fontFamily: 'PT Sans',
            },
            enabled: true
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineWidth: 1,
        endOnTick: true,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: true,
        minPadding: 0,
        lineColor: '#bfbfbf',
        minRange: 2,
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#bfbfbf',
            width: 1,
            value: 0,
            zIndex: 5
        }],
        labels: {
            format: '{value} %',
            style: {
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
            }
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
        type: 'polygon',
        color: 'rgba(100,100,100, 0.1)',
        data: [[0, 0], [20, 10], [20, 0]]
        },

        {
        type: 'polygon',
        color: 'rgba(100,100,100, 0.1)',
        data: [[0, 0], [20, 20], [20, 0]]
        },


        {type: 'scatter',
        marker: {
         radius: 10,
            symbol: 'circle',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                }
            }
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            x: -8,
            y: -8,
            fontFamily: 'PT Sans',
            color: 'rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8)',
            format: '{series.name}'
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: 'Volatility: {point.x}%<br>Exp. Return: {point.y}%'
        },name: 'United-States',color: 'rgba(215, 40, 40, 0.6)',data: [[15.8,5.9]]},
        //Rest of the data here, repeating in the same format as above^^
    },
    function (chart) { // on complete
        chart.renderer.label('<div style="font-size:18px;">0.1 Sharpe Ratio</div>',
            $(chart.container).width() - 200,
            $(chart.container).height() - 150,
            true)
            .css({
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
            })            
            .add();

        chart.renderer.label('<div style="font-size:18px;">0.2 Sharpe Ratio</div>',
            $(chart.container).width() - 200,
            $(chart.container).height() - 250,
            true)
            .css({
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
            })            
            .add();
        });
});
```

And it produced this result:

[image: Result render]

Thanks again for the tips!